# Working options without API's in PHP

Tags: php

There is a site that does not have a standalone search or API product available at this time, and I need a PHP page which can get information another way. This site has a manual search function to pull data, is there a way for my page to go to the site, click on the search parameters that I need and pull the results into my page? Maybe there's a better way?

Example.

realestate.com.au, I want a user to enter the same search fields in my php file, go to realestate.com.au, plug in those search parameters in that site, then as the results of my search come through, eg, 3 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms in the Suburb of Marylands, I get the price of all the results and in my page calculate the median price, and that field gets outputted to the user on my screen.

Now I have no code for this as I don't even know how to start. I cant do most of it if I can find out a way to start by having php go to realestate.com.au (not redirecting the user there, just hooking into the website) and doing the search.

I hope I make sense.
Regards

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: You'll need to "scrape" the data. There are thousands of examples of this online, you just need to search. Also, you'll almost definitely in violation of the terms of service of the site.

Comment: If they don't provide you with an interface (API) to search their website then probably they don't want their site to be scraped like that. However that being said, you could look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do the site owners want what you're trying to do?

Comment: "realestate.com.au" terms expressly forbid this

Comment: actually there is a site, best place to start is [http://webtools.realestate.com.au/] and you could curl for something like Marylands with `curl 'http://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=\{"channel":"buy","filters":\{"replaceProjectWithFirstChild":true,"propertyTypes":\["house"\],"priceRange":\{"minimum":0\}\},"localities":\[\{"subdivision":"NSW","postcode":"2287"\}\]\}'` this would return json which you can parse as you like

Comment: and using JS to do a fetch [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saramic/11scr07p/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat complex... more than I can cover here. but here is the general steps involved:

**1) Build your URL**
From your target site, find out what the URL looks like on the search results page. That should tell you how to build your URL for later on.

**2) Use CURL to retrieve your custom results page**
Using the format that you saw above, sned a request for that page using CURL. Only you will be substituting your visitors search terms into the URL.

**3) Scrape the resulting page**
CURL will fetch the HTML from the search results page. You will then have to iterate through that result and pull out the needed data using DIV IDs and classes.

**4) Serve the final results to your visitor**
Drop the scraped data into your own page and send to the browser.

See aslo:
http://voices.yahoo.com/how-scrape-web-page-using-php-curl-5442987.html

NOTE: I would make sure you have permission to scrape the site.

Comment: `I would make sure you have permission to scrape the site.` Which usually is not the case

Comment: Agreed. Even if not explicitly stated on the site, copyrights are automatically given to any original work until the author grants permission for use. And even then, be sure to get the permission in writing.

Comment: thanks all i was not aware their were copyright issues. I will scrape just to learn how to use it, but I will get permission first. thanks all